# How to set the ThreadPool Size in Slick?

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

How do I set the threadPool Size in slick ?

Here is my config:

```
pp {
  profile = "slick.jdbc.OracleProfile$"
  db {
    url                 = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@52.4.90.244:1521:pp"
    driver              = oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    keepAliveConnection = true
    connectionPool      = disabled
    user                = "xxx"
    password            = "xxx"
  }
}
```

I am actually doing only one query, in streaming, do I really need a threadPool ? My goal is simply to retrieve all the rows from a table.

So far i am having the following error:

```
*** (s.basic.BasicBackend.stream) Signaling onSubscribe(slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$JdbcStreamingActionContext@76f2bbc1)
*** (s.basic.BasicBackend.action) #1: [fused] cleanUp
      try: andThen
        1: PushStatementParameters StatementParameters(ForwardOnly,ReadOnly,null,null,100)
        2: StreamingResultAction [select * FROM DRUG]
*** (s.basic.BasicBackend.action) #2: SynchronousDatabaseAction.Pin
*** (s.basic.BasicBackend.action) #3: [fused] andThen
      1: PushStatementParameters StatementParameters(ForwardOnly,ReadOnly,null,null,100)
      2: StreamingResultAction [select * FROM DRUG]
*** (s.basic.BasicBackend.action) #4: SynchronousDatabaseAction.Pin
*** (s.basic.BasicBackend.action) #5: SynchronousDatabaseAction.Unpin
*** (s.basic.BasicBackend.stream) Signaling onError(java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef$$anon$2@3061964c rejected from slick.util.AsyncExecutor$$anon$2$$anon$1@55d260cc[Shutting down, pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0])
```

Comment: are you at version 3.2.3?

Comment: Yes that is the version I use

Comment: Have you looked at this? it might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37495523/slick-confused-about-numthreads-and-best-practice-for-good-performance

Comment: Yes i just found out after asking the question :) !! thanks anyway. But i guess my problem is different. I need to ask a series of questions because slick does not work properly for me at all.

Comment: try to remove the line connectionpool=disabled. unless the database is a in-memory instance you will likely need a pool